# With the Autodesk viewer API, is there a way to find out if the IFC model being displayed, has been converted to svf2 using legacy conversion or v3

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

We are trying to move from converting IFC's to svf2 using the conversion method legacy to v3. But we would still keep older models that had been converted using the legacy conversion method.

I have not found a answer to this after searching

I would like to know if is possible to figure out which method has been used, using only the JS viewer API

Answer (score 0):

To change IFC conversion method, you must re-translate the model with new translation job config.

```json
{
    "input": {
        "urn": "dXJ...Yw"
    },
    "output": {
        "formats": [
            {
                "type": "svf2",
                "views": [
                    "3d"
                ],
                "advanced": {
                    "conversionMethod": "v3"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Therefore,
If you want to keep the old model (translated results using the legacy method), please duplicate your source IFC model with a different filename as the OSS object name/key, and then request translation with a different conversion method.

To know which IFC conversion method was used, we can check the manifest by calling [GET {urn}/manifest](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/manifest/urn-manifest-GET/), and find `IFC Loader` in the properties like below, `IFC Loader: 1` is legacy, `IFC Loader: 2` is modern, and `IFC Loader: 3` is v3,

```json
{
    "type": "manifest",
    "hasThumbnail": "true",
    "status": "success",
    "progress": "complete",
    "region": "US",
    "urn": "dXJ...mM",
    "version": "1.0",
    "derivatives": [
        {
            "name": "COBieChallengeModel_2023.ifc",
            "hasThumbnail": "true",
            "status": "success",
            "progress": "complete",
            "properties": {
                "Document Information": {
                    "Navisworks File Creator": "LcNwcLoaderPlugin:lcldifc",
                    "IFC Application Name": "Autodesk Revit 2023 (ENU)",
                    "IFC Application Version": "2023",
                    "IFC Schema": "IFC2X3",
                    "IFC Loader": "3",
                    "nwModelToWorldTransform": [
                        1,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        1,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0,
                        1,
                        0,
                        0,
                        0
                    ]
                }
            },

            //...
```